# How to add an action result? mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I need to create an action result to display the contents of my list.

I have the following code in my Movie.cs class. I need help with creating the action result. My code is:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
 {
  public class Movie
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
  }

 public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{      
    public  List<Movie> GetMoviesList()
    {

        List<Movie> lmovie = new List<Movie>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dev01;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Movies", con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        con.Close();


        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            Movie mv = new Movie();
            mv.ID = Convert.ToInt32( r["ID"]);
            mv.Title = r["Title"].ToString();
            mv.Price = Convert.ToInt32(r["Price"]);
            mv.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r["ReleaseDate"]);
            mv.Genre = r["Genre"].ToString();
            lmovie.Add(mv);

        }
        return lmovie;
    }

}
}
```

This is my action result in the MoviesController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(-----);
}
```

Comment: Try reading this to understand Asp.Net MVC basis -> http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Instanciate your datacontext in your controller and return your results to your view so you can go and represent them.

MoviesController:

```
  public ActionResult Index(){
    var context = new MovieDBContext();
    var allMovies = context.GetMoviesList();
    return View(allMovies);
  }
```

Default behaviour with Razor views enabled: This will search for the view file 'Index.cshtml' in the /Views/Movies folder. You can create your index.Cshtml with a model of List so you can use the 'Model' as a list iterator in your view.

But; go and read any getting started tutorial about c# / MVC which should give you a better idea what goes where. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I tried the code and I get this error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcMovie.Models.Movie]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcMovie.Models.Movie'

Comment: This means your view 'Index.cshtml' is expecting a different model (Movie) instead what he got - a List of movies.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{
    var dbContext = new MovieDBContext();
    var movieList= dbContext .GetMoviesList();
    return View(movieList);
}
```

Make sure your index view(index.cshtml) is strongly typed to a collection of `Movie`

```
@model List<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <h2>@item.Title</h2>
}
```

**Note :** You are inheriting `DBContext` class to create your `MovieDBContext` where you have your `GetMoviesList` method. But in the method, You are using typical ADO.NET code to get data. In that case, You do not even need to inherit your class from `DBContext`.

If you inherit from DBContext, You can make use of Entity framework to get the data without writing all those lines of codes. Checkout some entity framework tutorial on the internet to see how it works.